# Translate application Android

Tags: java, android

> ive just started lookin up to Java and creating app, i know i should
>   start and improove slowly, but i need quickly some helps with makin a
>   Translator.apk using Bing API translator, cause google one are now
>   only aviable if u pay them.
>
> i saw a litle exemple where i downloaded the Jar file(which i put it
>   in /libs and mine came out like this:

```
import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText in, out;
Button trns;
String inPut;
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Translate.setClientId("hidden");
Translate.setClientSecret("hidden");
super.onCreate();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
trns = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
in = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
out = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
inPut = in.getText().toString();    
trns.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
String translatedText = Translate.execute(inPut, Language.GERMAN,
Language.FRENCH);
out.setText(translatedText);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Probably it's all wrong i know, that's why i need help   Guess i have to add Internet permission to the manifest(how ? and do i have to make some controll after?) I studied at school some basic C# so im used to the grouBox which i didnt find with eclipse. What's the nearest thing with it where i can put a list of all selectable language to translate?

Answer (score 2):

Use a spinner for dropdown-like behavior. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

If you are not comfortable with android development, but have some html knowledge, you can simply create a webpage and put it inside a WebView. It makes android development very easy for web developers. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

To set internet permission in the manifest: Add this to the manifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, Bing has webservices that you can call to translate text to different languages, and they are so easy to implement as well from any language (in your case, Java or Javascript).

See here http://www.microsofttranslator.com/tools/

Comment: I know i should learn before(ive started few weeks ago) but this its really urgent for me :P and i have no idea how to do these things. i dont know al method to use onlines stuff, or sms , or network ecc. 
So if its not too long and not  aproblem id just like to know what should i write inside the try and catch :\

Comment: Oh ive just seen the WebView, but i would still dont know how to create a dictionary with HTML so i would put google translate inside the webView and wouldnt be so helpful

Answer (score 0):

In android it's called a [Spinner](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fwidget%2FSpinner.html&ei=eyyAULfMH-zriQKHhYCIBA&usg=AFQjCNH8qaN46fA-CLWH9p_wfFPM6C8H1w&sig2=6E187VEZiRpFJS2iPlhD_Q)